# Python Azure Function works in local emulator but no HTTP triggers found when deploying

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have 5 Azure Functions I'm developing, and 4 of them deploy and work fine, just having this trouble with one of them.

I have the Azure Functions Core Tools installed and Azurite running as a VSCode plugin, and am able to run my function with no errors by calling `func start --python --verbose` from CLI.

I can call the HTTP trigger from the local emulator and it returns a correct response.

When I deploy to Azure Functions, the logs end in `No HTTP triggers found` with no errors shown throughout the deploy process.

I've been able to download the web package via SCM and confirmed that the files are the same in there as they are in my development environment.

What steps can I take to get more verbose information out of the Azure Functions environment to help with identifying the error which is causing the HTTP trigger to fail to deploy to production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a custom environment variable missing from production which was present in development.

I worked that one out on my own, I never found a useful error message to point to the fact that that is what was happening.

If anyone knows how I'd be supposed to get a meaningful error message out of Azure Functions to point to such an error then please share, but I'll leave this answer here for anyone else going through the same thing, hopefully it helps you too.